# Calling a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table it's somehow like this:

[image]
and the question was "Call all employees under Tom:"

Output shall be:
[image]

Comment: Fun! If you run into trouble, you can ask a question!

Comment: BTW, how do you know who's under Tom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where Id > (select Id from TABLE_NAME where Name = 'Tom')
```

Answer (score 3):

Are IDs always going to be ordered?
If so, what yo want is SELECT the rows which ID is larger than Tom's ID

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE Id > (SELECT Id FROM employees WHERE Name = 'Tom');
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking ?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(t1.id) 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.position = t.position AND t1.department = t.department
             );
```